# Puppeter dont make right click in all links

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to do right click in all links in a page but is not working. I want to do right click because i have to test some events for mousedown, so i dont have to do necesarily click on them. I use right click so the links dont reload the page o redirect

```
    (async () => {
  const url = 'yourUrlHere';
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(url);
  
  // test1
  const elHandleArray = await page.$$('a');
  for (const el of elHandleArray) {
    console.log('### Clicking...' + el);
    await el.evaluate(b => b.click({ button: "right", }));
    //await el.click({ button: "right" });
    
  } 
 // test2
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      const elHandleArray = document.querySelectorAll('a');
      for (const el of elHandleArray) {
        console.log('### Clicking...' + el);
        el.click({ button: "right" });
      }
    });
 
 // test3
 const aElems = await page.$$('a');
  for (let i = 0; i < aElems.length; i++) {
    const elem = aElems[i];
    console.log('### Click element: ', i);
    await page.waitForTimeout(elem);
    await page.evaluate((e) => {
      document.querySelector(e).click({ button: "right", });
    }, elem);
  } 
})();
```